# HTML5 Video Triggered by a graphic elswere on the page

Tags: html, video, hyperlink, graphic

I am trying to figure out a way to have a static image appear were the video will be when a visitor first comes to my webpage. I would like to have a graphic button that if clicked will trigger the video to play. This graphic would be elswere on the page not in or on top of the video. So, I guess I am looking for how to do 2 things.

1. Play an html5 video by clicking a graphic elswere on the page
2. When that video is played it should swap out the static graphic version for the active video version. Ideally, once played the static version would replace the video and be reset to play again.

Any help with this would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should do the trick, just make sure to point 'video' and 'image' to their respective URLs.

```
<script>
    function doVideo()
    {
        var video = "myvideo.mp4";
        document.getElementById("videoimgdiv").innerHTML = "<video autoplay onended=\"doImage()\"><source src=\"" + video + "\"\></video>";
    }

    function doImage()
    {
        var image = "http://us.123rf.com/400wm/400/400/podlesnova/podlesnova0906/podlesnova090600034/5117393-small-red-furry-kitten-with-blue-eyes.jpg";
        document.getElementById("videoimgdiv").innerHTML = "<img onclick=\"doVideo()\" src=\"" + image + "\"/>";
    }

</script>

<div id="videoimgdiv">
  <img onclick="doVideo()"src="http://us.123rf.com/400wm/400/400/podlesnova/podlesnova0906/podlesnova090600034/5117393-small-red-furry-kitten-with-blue-eyes.jpg" />
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you very much for the reply. I tried this out and it seems to work in that it swaps the image for video controls but for some reason will not trigger the video clip to play. Also this solution could work for me but if at all possible I was hoping that the graphic button I click to play the video will reside in another location on the page and would not be in the same div as the video and static image of the video. The trigger button would always be visible and once pushed it would swap the image for a video in another div on the page. If not the other way could work. Thanks!

Comment: You can add another element which triggers the video and just set the "onclick" attribute to "doVideo()". For example: <button type="button" onclick="doVideo()">Click Me!</button>

Comment: I see what you mean. I got the trigger to work but the video still just comes up as controls and does not play. Here is the code, anything i should change?...
    function doVideo()
    {
        var video = "video/dr_perkins.mp4";"autoplay" 
        document.getElementById("videoimgdiv").innerHTML = "<video controls onended=\"doImage()\"><source src=\"" + video + "\></video>";
    }
    function doImage()
    {
        var image = "images/db-video-placeholder.png";
        document.getElementById("videoimgdiv").innerHTML = "<img onclick=\"doVideo()\" src=\"" + image + "/>";
    }

Comment: That's easy, you just have to change the attributes of the <video> tag. take a look at http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_video.asp, just remove the 'controls' in the 'doVideo()' function, removing the play button and timeline, etc., and replace it with the 'autoplay' attribute, which is self explanatory.

Comment: document.getElementById("videoimgdiv").innerHTML = "<video autoplay onended=\"doImage()\"><source src=\"" + video + "\></video>";

Comment: Thanks for the auto play info. The video still does not play when it swaps the the mp4. Is there something more I need to add to the js? Here is the code as it is now... function doVideo()
    {
        var video = "video/jgpearslogo.mp4"  
        document.getElementById("videoimgdiv").innerHTML = "<video autoplay onended=\"doImage()\"><source src=\"" + video + "\></video>"; 
    }

Comment: I just noticed an error on my part; in the JavaScript, there were two instances of starting " character but no end " characters. This is the reason the video and photo failed. I edited the answer, note the ... <source src=\"" + video + "\"\></video> ... where the original was ... <source src=\"" + video + "\></video>. It should word fine now, it does on Chromium running on Gentoo for me.